# GROUPBY many to many with itself

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have a User table that has a many to many relation with itself, and I would like to get all the pairs of users with this specific relation. The problem is, in the relation table I store users like that:

```
+------+---------------+
| User |   relation    |
+------+---------------+
| id   | left_user_id  |
| name | right_user_id |
| ...  | ...           |
+------+---------------+
```

So when I do a basic

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM relation LEFT OUTER JOIN user AS user_1 ON user_1.id = relation.left_user_id
              LEFT OUTER JOIN user AS user_2 ON user_2.id = relation.right_user_id 
GROUP BY left_user_id, right_user_id;
```

I sometimes get two results for the same pair (for example sometimes (Adam, Eva) and (Eva, Adam) which are the same pair). What I would like to achieve is just one pair: (Adam, Eva).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM relation r
LEFT OUTER JOIN user AS user_1 ON user_1.id = r.left_user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user AS user_2 ON user_2.id = r.right_user_id 
GROUP BY LEAST(r.left_user_id, r.right_user_id), GREATEST(r.left_user_id, r.right_user_id);
```

Or in this case where you don't need the joins:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM relation 
GROUP BY LEAST(left_user_id, right_user_id), GREATEST(left_user_id, right_user_id);
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more? I don't get why it works, it seems like LEAST and GREATEST doesn't do anything. I understand that they do but what? Does It remove the reference from the alias and the db just groups by sheer values?

Comment: When you `GROUP BY left_user_id, right_user_id` the combinations `1, 2` and `2, 1` are different so they are different groups, but when you `GROUP BY LEAST(left_user_id, right_user_id)` the combinations `1, 2` and `2, 1` are grouped under the same group `1, 2` because LEAST(1, 2) = 1 = LEAST(2, 1) and GREATEST(1, 2) = 2 = GREATEST(2, 1)

Answer (score 0):

The `left join`s should not be necessary.  The key is simply using `least()` and `greatest()`.  That would be:

```
SELECT LEAST(r.left_user_id, r.right_user_id) as user_id_1,
       GREATEST(r.left_user_id, r.right_user_id) as user_id_2,
       COUNT(*)
FROM relation 
GROUP BY user_id_1, user_id_2;
```

The one caveat with this approach is that the pair in the result set may not be in the original data -- in that order.  So, if you had "Eve"/"Adam" once in the data, then it would return:  "Adam"/"Eve"/1.  That can be addressed, if necessary.